# Rails 3 - Splat attr_accessible with Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, splat

I'm making `typed`options dynamic by moving them to a new model, as you can see before I was using a constant to make the columns `t_a, t_b, t_c` accessible with `*TYPED_DATA`, but now that the model has been migrated, i can't do it anymore. Is there a something I'm missing.

By the way, this fails when I've re-run my specs with FactoryGirl.

```
class Rules < ActiveRecord::Base
  #TYPED_DATA = %w{a b c}.map { |t| t.prepend('t_').to_sym }

  attr_accessible :name, *Typed.prefixed
end

# typed.rb
class Typed < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.prefixed
    Typed.pluck(:name).map { |name| name.prepend('t_').to_sym }
  end
end
```

What is the best option to dynamically expose those attributes?

Comment: what error do you get in your tests?

Comment: That t_a is not accessible to mass assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this solution doesn't solve the technical issue of using AR query with splat. 
It solves the main issue which is make those dynamic fields accessible, specially in cases where the majority of fields need to be accessible, it's better to rely on the ones you want to protect.

```
class Rules < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_protected :id, :created_at, :updated_at
end
```